# Transform breaks parent overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a box inside a circle, with css transform. The circle has the overflow property set to hidden. But when the rotation happens it shows the overflow that should be hidden. This is happening in chrome.

[Here](http://codepen.io/KatT84/pen/Ezgbw) is an example of the problem.

Can any one help me solve this?

Comment: You can't hide elements with  `border-radius`. The element still render square space .

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in webkit.

The bug report can be found here:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68196

An in-depth discussion of the bug can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218&q=label%3AWebKit-ID-68196-NEW&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Someone in the link I gave to the discussion of the bug seems to have a workaround.  They've provided a jsfiddle for it in the last post in that discussion.  I was not able to get it to work for your codepen, however.

Comment: Thanks, i already tried that whit no luck, it doesn't seam to work in this case.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish something similar with an image and absolute positioning.